Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении ниже?
Как тут не волноваться: смотрит на тебя исподлобья и что думает, никто не знает.

Можно тире поставить:
Как тут не волноваться: смотрит на тебя исподлобья и чтО думает— никто не знает.
Тире характерно для изъяснительного придаточного в препозиции. Три основы, общая бессоюзная связь отменяет запятую перед И.

А можете ещё на мои неотвеченные ответить?

Всё верно.
Как тут не волноваться: смотрит на тебя исподлобья и что думает, никто не знает.
